# convert a string into epoch time

Tags: python

I tried to convert a string into epoch time but failed.

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import parser

dt = '2017-01-01 00:00:00'
dt = parser.parse(dt)
print(dt)

print (datetime(dt).timestamp())
```

Here is error:

```
 print (datetime(dt).timestamp())
   TypeError: an integer is required (got type datetime.datetime)
```

Comment: dt is already a datetime object so you can just call the timestamp() method on dt: `dt.timestamp()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to use your datetime instance:

```
print (dt.timestamp())
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp):

> Return POSIX timestamp corresponding to the datetime **instance**.

What you are currently doing is passing the parsed datetime object to the [datetime constructor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) (`datetime(dt)`)which expects integers.